# Save barchart as image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

so I made a barchart

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def barchart(new_object_list):

y_axel = []
i=0
for i in range(10):
    y_axel.append(int(new_object_list[i].count))
    i +=1


x_axel = []
j = 0
for j in range(10):
    x_axel.append(str(new_object_list[j].word))
    j +=1


y_pos = np.arange(len(y_axel))
plt.bar(y_pos, y_axel)
plt.xticks(y_pos, x_axel)
plt.show()

return;
```

Now I want to save this as a file, but how exactly do I do that?

Also, this chart produces the occurences of the 10 most common words in a text, and how many times they occur. Some of these words are long, so the words which I have in the x-axis tend to "blend" together and make it very hard to read, how can I adjust that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried: `plt.savefig('mybarchart.png')`?

Comment: It works, cheers mate!